Adding 001 002 003 etc to all files in the same folder
I have a folder with many files. Something like 200-300 files. I tried with PowerShell to add each file 001, 002 and so on.
It means if I have in the folders, these files:
hello.mp4
buy.mp4
gohome.mp4

They will be after the PowerShell script:
001_hello.mp4
002_buy.mp4
003_gohome.mp4

And so on for all the files. I tried:
$nr = 1
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\A\Desktop\1' -Filter '*.*' -File) | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:D3}{1}' -f ($script:nr++), $_.Extension }

But, it renames all the files and I want to keep the name and just to add 001_beforethefilename.

Try the following script. It loops through each file, generates a variable to hold the new filename (3-digit number followed by the current filename). Then, renames the file and increments the counter.
$x = 1
Get-ChildItem -File | foreach { 
$name = $x.ToString("000") + $_.Name
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $name
$x += 1
}


Your script doesn't add the _ between name and number. So you would do something like this: $name = "$($x.ToString("000"))_$($_.Name)"

$nr = 1  
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\A\Desktop\1' -File |
Rename-Item -NewName { ($Script:n++).ToString('000') + '_' + $_.Name }

In short, You nee to replace '$__.Extension' with '$_.Name'
Caution: Allways test first with the'-WhatIf' switch
Tip: sort it first with 'CreationTime' in order to add the numbers based on time Created like this:
$nr = 1  
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\A\Desktop\1' -File |
sort CreationTime |
Rename-Item -NewName { ($Script:n++).ToString('000') + '_' + $_.Name }

